# How to get Next month date from today date (i.e) exactly one month expires from today date

Tags: sql, datetime, stored-procedures

I have maintained two datas into my table

1 column     2 column
PaidDate    validitydate

in padidate ill give insert todaydate. but in validity date i may either insert validity for 1 week/1 month.

I have used validity=DATEADD(Day,7,@paiddate) to insert validity for 1 week. but how to gtet the validity for 1 month from todays date

Comment: What date would you expect to get for 1 month after 31st January?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't that just:

```
validity = DATEADD(month, 1, @paiddate)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`DATE_ADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) supports units.